# How to create a unique ID for a grouping of rows with sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have the below db schema:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    transaction_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    total_price integer not null
);
CREATE TABLE order_items (
    transaction_id integer REFERENCES orders(transaction_id),
    SKU integer not null,
    product_name text not null,
    unit_price integer not null,
    quantity integer not null
);
```

Data is sent to the db via this flask code:

```
@app.route('/load_ajax', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def load_ajax():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.get_json()
        for group in groupby(data, itemgetter('name')):
            id, data_list = group
            for d in data_list:
                print d['subtotal']
                db = get_db()
                db.execute('insert into order_items (SKU, product_name, unit_price, quantity) values (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                           [d['sku'], d['name'], d['price'], d['quantity']])
                db.execute('insert into orders (total_price) values (?)',
                           [d['subtotal']])
                db.commit()
        return jsonify(location=url_for('thankyou'))
```

A read of the orders table gives this:

```
1|1187.86
2|1187.86
3|1187.86
4|1187.86
5|1187.86
6|1187.86
7|102.92
8|102.92
9|102.92
10|102.92
```

and a read of the order_items table give this:

```
|ASD|Hot Sauce|10.99|1
|JKL|Chilli Peppers|8.99|1
|UIO|Sip 'n' Sizzle T-Shirt|10.5|1
|MEE|Energy Drinks|10.99|1
|FUE|Literally, Anything|1|1
|POL|Burger Ryan|1000|1
|ASD|Hot Sauce|10.99|1
|JKL|Chilli Peppers|8.99|1
|UIO|Sip 'n' Sizzle T-Shirt|10.5|1
|MEE|Energy Drinks|10.99|1
```

What I am trying to accomplish is generating a unique transaction ID that would be given to each item in a particular order.

First I'm not sure why transaction_id column in the order_items table is not appearing.  Second, how can I get a table that might look like this:

orders:

```
1|1187.86
1|1187.86
1|1187.86
1|1187.86
1|1187.86
1|1187.86
2|102.92
2|102.92
2|102.92
2|102.92
```

order_items:

```
1|ASD|Hot Sauce|10.99|1
1|JKL|Chilli Peppers|8.99|1
1|UIO|Sip 'n' Sizzle T-Shirt|10.5|1
1|MEE|Energy Drinks|10.99|1
1|FUE|Literally, Anything|1|1
1|POL|Burger Ryan|1000|1
2|ASD|Hot Sauce|10.99|1
2|JKL|Chilli Peppers|8.99|1
2|UIO|Sip 'n' Sizzle T-Shirt|10.5|1
2|MEE|Energy Drinks|10.99|1
```

Is this something I can do sqlite?

EDIT:
This is how I changed CL.'s answer to fit my code:

```
@app.route('/load_ajax', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def load_ajax():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.get_json()
        db = get_db()
        c = db.cursor()
        c.execute('insert into orders (total_price) values (?)', [data[0]['subtotal']])
        transaction_id = c.lastrowid
        for group in groupby(data, itemgetter('name')):
            id, data_list = group
            for d in data_list:
                db.execute('insert into order_items (transaction_id, SKU, product_name, unit_price, quantity) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                           [transaction_id, d['sku'], d['name'], d['price'], d['quantity']])
        db.commit()
    return jsonify(location=url_for('thankyou'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transaction_id` column in the `order_items` table is not appearing because you are not inserting anything into it.

You do not want to have duplicate rows in the `orders` table.
Insert an order only once (I am assuming a single POST is a single order):

```
    data = request.get_json()
    subtotal = data......
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute('insert into orders (total_price) values (?)', [subtotal])
    transaction_id = c.lastrowid
    for group in groupby(data, itemgetter('name')):
        id, data_list = group
        for d in data_list:
            db.execute('insert into order_items (transaction_id, SKU, product_name, unit_price, quantity) values (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                       [transaction_id, d['sku'], d['name'], d['price'], d['quantity']])
    db.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I had to make a few amendments to fit my data structures (posted above in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mapping table between orders and order_item

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    transaction_id integer primary key autoincrement,
);

CREATE TABLE order_mapping (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    transaction_id foreign key references orders(transaction_id),
    item_id foreign key references order_items(item_id)
);


CREATE TABLE order_items (
    item_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    SKU integer not null,
    product_name text not null,
    unit_price integer not null,
    quantity integer not null
);
```